# Is it possible to create dynamic AI path "on fly"?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

How to dynamically create AI path between two objects?

For example, one AI character must go to the another AI character.

Is it possible to make AI path with logic "goto in front of the object", "goto in backside of the object" and etc? How to programm this AI logic - with blueprint or with C++?

Something like http://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC2/AI+Sequence 
[image]
<sub>(source: [cryengine.com](http://docs.cryengine.com/download/attachments/1048791/SimpleSequence.jpg?version=1&modificationDate=1366897709000&api=v2))</sub>

Can you provide examples for blueprint and for C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is very easy in blueprints.

UE4 creates a navmesh for your level that the AI can use to create dynamic paths to world coordinates or actors within the level.

The following image shows the different blueprint nodes you can use to make AI characters move dynamically around your level:

[image: Blueprint nodes for AI move commands]

Comment: Hello and thank you! But what about logic "move to the right (left, back, front) side of the object"? For example, what will do "Move to Actor" ? Will objects be face to face or it will be random position near target object? In Unity3D there are http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html and http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html . How to programm blueprint to move to object and stay at the right side of the target object?

Comment: The move to actor function will stop once your AI is within the acceptance radius of your target. If you want to move to the right of your target object then you have to do some vector math: Find out where your target object is looking at so you can calculate where its right side is by rotating that vector 90 degrees. Scale and add that vector to your target object's world position and move your AI to the resulting coordinates.

Comment: Wow! Really good idea! But why it is not automated, like in Unity3D with Transform.right?

Comment: And how to calculate degrees, scaling and another with blueprints? I know, how it is possible to write in C# or C++, but I do not know, how to do it using blueprints.